# Can't change the Center of Map according to the address in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, webforms

I am really new in using Google Map API. I wanted to create an Asp.Net project using Google Map API. Here I can able to show the desired location by populating the map from my database.But I am having difficulties changing the center of the map which was entered in the text box. I can dynamically get the latitude & longitude of the address and also placed my image marker on the map according to the text box. But it doesn't change the center of the map.

This is my aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Asp_GMap.Main2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Show/Add multiple markers to Google Maps from database in asp.net 
website</title>
    <style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDC0pSCu_15c1krbw5yoRnU51uIie6j8K4&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var latitude = 22.347537;
    var longitude = 91.812332;
    function initialize() {



        var value="";
        var latitude = 22.347537;
        var longitude = 91.812332;
        var mymap;
        var img = 'Images/position.png';
        var mapOptions;
        value = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
        var address = value;

                           //////////to show ATM booth
        var markers = JSON.parse('<%=DataTableLoading() %>');

        if (value != "") {



            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
                        map: map,
                        title: "I am here",
                        Icon: img
                    });

                }
            });
        }


 mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
//  marker:true
};
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
mapOptions);

for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);


         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title
    });



(function(marker, data) {

// Attaching a click event to the current marker
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
infoWindow.setContent(data.Description);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
})(marker, data);
}
    }

</script>



</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span>Location:</span>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox> <br /><br 
/>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1_SeachAddress" runat="server" Text="Button" 
OnClientClick="initialize()"  />
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Code behind....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Asp_GMap
{
    public partial class Main2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string CS = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCON_STRING"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public string DataTableLoading()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS) )
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title=City,lat=Latitude,lng=Longitude,Street,Description from AtmAddress", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Can you guys please help me to find a suitable solution for the problems in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to center the map yourself with `panTo`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function centerMap(lat, lng) {
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        map.panTo(location);
    }
</script>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

There is also something called `setCenter`. Not tested that but I'm guessing it also centers the map, but without the scrolling.

Comment: VDWWD, In which position I have to add this code or in where I have to edit my code with this.

Comment: When you want to pan the map to a new location.